# When you rejuvenate as a lich, what do you look like? What does a newly formed lich looks like?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters

In the SRD, the lich's appearance is described as :

> Once fine robes hang in tatters from this withered corpse's frame. A
>   pale blue light shines from where its eyes should be.

In 3.5,  Monster Manual 3.5. (Wizards of the Coast), pp. 166–168 :

> Liches were generally gaunt and skeletal with withered flesh stretched
>   tight across horribly visible bones, but could vary greatly in
>   appearance depending on their age. Some appeared as skeletons dressed
>   in regal finery, yet others might appear to be nothing more than
>   lepers. Bright pinpoints of crimson light burned in the empty sockets
>   of those whose eyes had been destroyed or otherwise lost or were so
>   old they had simply rotted away.

When you rejuvenate :

> Rejuvenation (Su): When a lich is destroyed, its phylactery (which is
>   generally hidden by the lich in a safe place far from where it chooses
>   to dwell) immediately begins to rebuild the **undead spellcaster's body
>   nearby**. This process takes 1d10 days—if the body is destroyed before
>   that time passes, the phylactery merely starts the process anew. After
>   this time passes, the lich wakens fully healed (albeit without any
>   gear it left behind on its old body), usually with a burning need for
>   revenge against those who previously destroyed it.

My question are :

1. what will the undead spellcaster's body look like?
2. Will it look like it were before you were destroyed, or when you became a lich?
3. Whats the appearance of a lich? In 3.5, Aumvor the Undying one had bloated flesh and was obese.
4. Does any appearance affects games balance?
5. Can it look as the caster was when he was alive?

Answer (score 2):

The base description is, as you said, this one:

> Once fine robes hang in tatters from this withered corpse's frame. A pale blue light shines from where its eyes should be.

This is a generic description so it must be adapted for every character:

1. The undead spellcaster's body will look like the undead twisted version of the original spellcaster. Every character will see their eyes glowing in a pale blu light, some occasional rotting flesh might be spotted and the character in general will look emaciated, like if it wasn't eating for days. Obviously, a gnome lich will be small and an orc lich will be pretty big.
2. This is opinion based, but if I was the DM, I will have you rejuvenate every time as if you never died. See it as a check point, as if your character image is saved into the phylactery, and the phylactery itself only knows one way to rejuvenate you.
3. See point 1
4. Sure it does, try to go in a city while you look like a lich. You will scare a lot of people ( people might die because of fear ) and guards won't be happy to have you around.. everyone that is brave enough will want to kill you.
5. No, you are a lich, not an alive creature. Lichdom comes with it's own flaws.